# getting random rows efficiently in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I select random rows from a table? The tables are quite big, what is the efficient way to get random rows from the table. Any suggestions?

http://ghtorrent.org/mysql.html

```
 ssh -L 3306:web.ghtorrent.org:3306 ghtorrent@web.ghtorrent.org

 on the other terminal 2
 mysql -u ght -h 127.0.0.1 ghtorrent
 select * from commits order by rand() limit 100000;
```

Comment: How "random" do you need it?

Comment: if the table=commits has one column=ID/Row#, it will make everything easy.

Comment: I would need pretty random, these records are organized by time, so I want to get rows from later part as well, 2008-2017 years to be precise

Comment: yes it does have a commit id column, does that help?

Comment: @Sphinx, how? can you elaborate?

Comment: If exists one commit id as primary key or unique, you can genearete one sql like "select * from commits where id in ('random1', 'random2'); random1, random2 can be generated by Sql Procedure or PHP (you added 'php' tag for this questions.) or other script languages.

Comment: for example: if the commit id is integer, you can generate random id using rand()*MAX(COMMIT_ID) in one loop.

Comment: "Random" is the opposite of what MySQL was built to do. You're probably better off explaining what your end goal is so we can suggest a better way to accomplish it. If you run queries like this you're going to piss off the people running GHT and have your access revoked.

Answer (score 1):

You can take an approximately 1% sample by doing:

```
select *
from commits 
where rand() < 0.01;
```

This will need to read the entire table, but it only needs to read it once.

This is probably the best way to get a *random* sample.  There are other ways to get a single random row or to get an arbitrary sample.

Comment: I think the table is in the order of 10 billion, do you think this will work?

Comment: @user3570187 . . . It will need to read all 10 billion rows, which will take some time.  A 1% sample is still pretty big (100 million rows).  Depending on the size of the sample, you may have to effectively read all the rows anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at this but I would suggest the following:

`$rand = rand();`

`select * from commits limit $rand,10000`;

Just make sure you pick a random number such that there are 10k rows after the random row number.

Answer (score 0):

Try below based on Mysql:

**Instructions:**

1. Using Repeat to generate the random ID if COMMIT_ID is the integer,
   then insert into the temp table.
2. Query out the rows from Table=Commits whose COMMIT_ID exist in the
   temp table=RetreivePoolTable.

**Disadvantage**: Some COMMIT_ID may not exists, so your scripts have to  execute this procedure several times until fecth enough rows.

If COMMIT_ID is one string like UUID, it will be more complicated, but the idea is same.

```
BEGIN
-- MySQL Version
DECLARE _MAX_COMMIT_ID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _RETRIEVE_ROWS INT DEFAULT 0; --the count of random rows you need
DECLARE _RETRIEVE_INDEX INT DEFAULT 0;
set _MAX_COMMIT_ID=0;
set _RETRIEVE_ROWS=10;  
set _RETRIEVE_INDEX=0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RetreivePoolTable (COMMIT_ID INT, PRIMARY KEY(COMMIT_ID));
SELECT MAX(COMMIT_ID) INTO _MAX_COMMIT_ID FROM Commits;
REPEAT

        INSERT INTO RetreivePoolTable VALUES (rand()*_MAX_COMMIT_ID);
        SET _RETRIEVE_INDEX = _RETRIEVE_INDEX + 1;

UNTIL _RETRIEVE_INDEX > _RETRIEVE_ROWS END REPEAT;
SELECT * from Commits where COMMIT_ID in (SELECT COMMIT_ID FROM RetreivePoolTable);
END
```

If you'd like query out random rows between specific date range and COMMIT_ID is in the order, Random ID generator will be:

```
set _MAX_COMMIT_ID=0;
set _MIN_COMMIT_ID=0;
SELECT MAX(COMMIT_ID) INTO _MAX_COMMIT_ID, MIN(COMMIT_ID) INTO _MIN_COMMIT_ID FROM Commits where COMMIT_DATE between date1 and date2;
INSERT INTO RetreivePoolTable VALUES (rand()*(_MAX_COMMIT_ID-_MIN_COMMIT_ID)+_MIN_COMMIT_ID);
```