# how to input random numbers in a where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to get random records based on an id column which needs to be randomly selected. I cannot use `rand()` function due to the database restrictions. But I have an id column which if I can randomly generate and ask should solve the problem. Any suggestions on how I can input random numbers to the sql where clause. I am planning to get around **100000** random numbers to search for.  for example

```
select a,id from users where id in (20, 30);
```

Comment: "I cannot use rand() function due to the database restrictions. "  What does that mean?

Comment: Me too ... I'm curious to know what it means "I cannot use rand() function due to the database restrictions. "

Comment: the database is so huge, it has around 200 billion records or something so the query gets killed if it runs more than specific time

Comment: Create a temporary table, insert 100000 rand() numbers. Join.

Comment: I dont have access, privileges to do so, it is on server

Comment: see here for a more related discussion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348422/getting-random-rows-efficiently-in-mysql

Comment: See which technique here tickles your fancy:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to fetch random users, you can achive it with the following query.

`select top 100000 a,id from users ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: Will this run on MySQL?

Comment: I'm afraid. it is written for SQL server.

Comment: MySQL:  `SELECT a, id FROM users ORDER BY newid LIMIT 100000;`